# Django custom tag 'takes_context'

Tags: django, tags, django-context

I`m new with django (came from Grails), especially with all those custom tags that you have to deal with, instead of writing your variables directly inside the templates.

Well, what I need to do was something really simple, but for some reason is taking me a long time to finish. What I wish to do was make a tag that checks for me if the given path is equals my current url, and then returns the class if true.

```
<li class="{% check_url '/login/' 'current_page_item' %}">
    <a href="{% url social_login %}">login</a>
</li>
```

But, the problem came  when I tried to register the tag with takes_context :

**Caught TypeError while rendering: simple_tag() got an unexpected keyword argument 'takes_context**'

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def check_url(context, path, attr):
        if context['request'].environ.get('PATH_INFO') == path:
            return attr
        else:
            return ''
```

How can I fix it? Also, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Are you using hte latest development version of django (1.3.x?) or the stable 1.2.x? If so you can't use simple_tag in this way - http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/ . A simple quick way is perhaps to do something like {% ifequal request.get_full_path '/login/' %}class="current_page"{% endif %}.

Comment: I`m using django 1.2.5, I tried to do the quick way before, but I moved to custom tag for a clean view. The takes_context only works with inclusion_tag(not what I want)

Answer (score 2):

That's because `takes_context` is only available since **django 1.3**.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to do it (and to avoid hardcoded urls):

```
{% url social_login as the_url %}
{% ifequal the_url request.path %}
....
{% endif %}
```

Or check out something like [this](https://gnuvince.wordpress.com/2007/09/14/a-django-template-tag-for-the-current-active-page/)!